# Convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability, explain what I'm doing wrong.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I just started to study convergence of random variables and I'm trying to prove that $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X \implies X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$. By definition of convergence a.s. we have

\begin{align*}
&P(\{\omega : X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)\}) = P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n = X\right) = P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n - X = 0\right) = 1\\
&\Leftrightarrow  1 - P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n - X = 0\right) = 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n - X \neq 0\right) = 0 \quad\text{(complement)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |X_n - X| > \epsilon \right) = 0 \quad \forall\epsilon> 0
\end{align*}

and thus, I have 'proved' that $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X \Leftrightarrow X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$.

**I know this is wrong**, but I can't see what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake(s), thanks!

Comment: Are you accounting for the cases where $X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)$ does not converge at all?

Comment: Note that the condition for convergence in probability is that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon)  = 0$$
and not
$$P(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n - X| > \epsilon)  = 0.$$

Comment: You are assuming that $\lim X_n$ exists. So the argument makes liitle sense.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Thank you, I have misread the definition of convergence in probability.